# Merge 5200 hotel and 5200 flights at run time

Tags: algorithm, performance, merge

I already have a solution but it seems to me not the best one. I think I’m missing something.

Imagine that you have to merge flights and hotels in packages for a half of a year in advance for every week(26 weeks) for 200 destinations. It means that we have 200*26 = 5200 flights and hotels.

At the end you need to get the best combination price(hotel price + flight price) for every destination. It means that you will have 200 best packages at the end.

I currently have 2 indices in elastic search (hotel and flight) but elastic search is not a requirement.

Best performant solution is generating all of packages in advance in the third indice. It’s actually not the best solution because it takes a lot of server resources and time. Imagine that you have like 10 different filters and every filter has many values.  if every filter has 6 values then it will be like 200*26* 6^10 = 314,424,115,200 iterations. We were thinking about cloud, it might be an option. But I think that there should be an algorithm to merge 5200 hotels and flights at run time.

Performance is very important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we have a list of filters, for example, 1/2adults. So you need the best package for both of values. You have a list of markets, like Germany, Great Britain,..., hotel properties, board types ...

Comment: @Dukeling manageable for generating in advance? yes. In the case of generating at run time, not really. It takes seconds and it's unacceptable

Comment: The best answer you'd probably get at this stage is "group by week and destination, leading to a linear or linearithmic time algorithm (since you can directly find the corresponding hotel or flight)". If that's not satisfactory (e.g. if it doesn't make sense for your data), you should probably [edit] your question and elaborate with some more details regarding what the data looks like and how you want to query it (although it might end up being too broad either way).

Comment: I thought may be there is a way to arrange indices in a special way using special keys in elastic search or something. What you mentioned it's the first thing that came to mind as well. Another thing is all of this hotels are the same, so it's kind of static information about swimming pools, stars and staff(offers, prices are not). Api is written with PHP and Symfony. May be the technology is wrong and I should try nodejs or python and run something in threads.